# How do I get the BAM Add-Ons in BizTalk 2016/Excel 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam, biztalk-2016

I want to create a BAM activity/view. I have Office 32-bit.  Do I need to open some specific BAM spreadsheet/model first?

This page shows how it works in Excel 2007: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559526(v=bts.20).aspx But I haven't found anything for more recent versions.

If I open a new empty spreadsheet, and click Add-Ins, I see nothing but the following: 
[image]

If I right click "Add-Ins" and select "Customize Quick Access Toolbar", I then see this screen - which looks like probably what I need, but still don't know the exact procedure to add the BAM Adds here. 
[image]

It might be wiser to find and edit the file outside of Excel first: The add-in file is: "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Library\Bam.xla"

I clicked on "Business Activity Monitoring" - then what should I do next to get the menus needed to add the BAM Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you click the "Go" button to the right of "Manage Excel Add-Ins". 
Then the following box pops-up, and I can check "Business Activity Monitoring" and then "Ok". 
[image]

If it doesn't appear there, you can click the "Browse" button, go to the ""c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Library" folder and select "Bam.xla".

If you are in Excel 64-bit, instead of 32-bit, you will get this error: 
[image]

But so far, after doing that, I still don't see any new "BAM" menu in Excel.

I was seeing error:

> Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on
>   64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then
>   mark them with the PtrSafe attribute.

If you get that, it means you are probably on 64-bit, not 32-bit version of Excel.  I was told by another team they installed 32-bit, but low and behold, they did not.  You can check the version using the following steps: 
  1) File (menu)
  2) (click) Account 
  3) Click the square (almost doesn't look like a button that says "? About Excel"

[image]

After getting the 32-bit, it looks okay, the BAM menu appears as follows (under the "Add-Ins" tab: 
[image]

If you click the "BAM Activity" and get the error "Variable not defined", then see this link: https://oussov.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/bam-xla-variable-not-defined-error-in-excel/